# Zipping strings according to the longer string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Given 2 strings:

```
a='AAAAAAAA'
b='GGGG'
```

I'd like to have a result of

```
'AG','AG','AG','AG','A','A','A','A'
```

So far I've tried 2 ways and both of them are returning only 4 items

**Map approach:**

```
list(map(lambda x,y:x+y,a,b))
```

result:

```
'AG','AG','AG','AG'
```

**Zip approach:**

```
list(zip(a,b))
```

result:

```
('A','G'),('A','G'),('A','G'),('A','G')
```

Map method looks closer to what I'm looking for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) which accepts a `fillvalue` argument :

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> a='AAAAAAAA'
>>> b='GGGG'

>>> [''.join(i) for i in zip_longest(a,b,fillvalue='')]
['AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

If you want to do this without importing a library you can have a look at `zip_longest` source code.And you might note that this is the most pythonic way to do such task.

By the way you can use another approaches which are not pythonic and efficient, for example you can use `atr.ljust` to fill the `b` with a special character and makes its size equal to `a` then zip them and use a list comprehension to get the expected output :

```
>>> [''.join((i,j)) if j != '.' else i for i,j in zip(a,b.ljust(len(a),'.'))]
['AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

Comment: Do you know a solution that doesn't need importing libraries? Of course this one works great, I'm just trying to understand the logic behind Python itself a little bit better.

Comment: @Random, the required module is _standard Python_, so no external library is needed. You can take a look at the equivalent Python code for `zip_longest` in the module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

Comment: @wap26 Like I said - I'm more after a concept (i.e. one I could port to other language) not an API call

Comment: @Random As Wao26 said `itertools` is not an external lib, and if you can check the source to find the python code there.Anyway I edited the answer with another alternative which is not the way to go with such tasks.

Comment: IMHO, using `zip` or `itertools.zip_longest` is just the same ; i.e. simply using a _standard_ Python function.

Answer (score 2):

No imports is a strange request, however:

```
>>> a='AAAAAAAA'
>>> b='GGGG'
>>> [a[i: i + 1] + b[i: i + 1] for i in range(max(map(len, (a, b))))]
['AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

or

```
>>> [''.join(i) for i in zip(a, b)] + list(a[len(b):]) + list(b[len(a):])
['AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

importing itertools is a far better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
a='AAAAAAA'
b='GGGG'
listab=[] #declaring new list
for i in range(0,len(a)): #loops for length of a
    item = a[i:i+1] + b[i:i+1] #concatenates a letter from a and b
    listab.append(item) 
print (listab)
```

1. Program declares two variables a and b.
2. Declares an empty list
3. Starts a for loop assuming variable (a) is longer (you can always write an if statement to check which one is longer if need be)
4. `for i in range(0,len(a))` increases integer i from 0 to the length of (a)
5. Then add the letters at the same position in (a) and (b) and append to the empty list you created.

`string[start position: end position]` returns the part of the string between the start and the end-1 position.